# Case.SobjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, record-type, apexrest

`Case.SobjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();` returns null even when the user profile has Record types assigned.

Prototype of code below :

```
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt = Case.SobjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();
Map<id,string> rtmap = new Map<id,string>();
for(RecordTypeInfo r : rt)
{
    if(rt.isAvailable()){
        //add to the map rtmap 
    }
}  
return rtmap
```

Comment: I ran your code in Anonymous Apex, and got the following error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isAvailable() from the type List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo>`

So firstly you would need to change `rt.isAvailable()` to `r.isAvailable()`.

Comment: To check the original issue you stated (that `Case.SobjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();` returns null), I added a `System.debug(rt)` line immediately after the first line, and then only ran those first two lines. I confirmed that there are records present in `rt` in my sandbox org.

Can you please elaborate on where you have tried running this (e.g., an Apex Trigger, Anonymous Apex) and under which context(s) (e.g., System, particular user)?